# Sleep after echoing response

Tags: php

I have an API endpoint which performs an action based on a user's request, and then echoes a json response. This endpoint also needs to trigger a notification, but only after a 30 second delay. The reason is in case the user reverses their request within that delay (via another endpoint), which would would mean no notification should be sent. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
// response
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'success' => 1,
        'updateUser' => $updateUser['ok'],
        'updateTarget' => $updateTarget['ok'],
        'updateActivity' => $updateActivity['ok']
    )
);

// send push notification after delay
sendDelayedNotification($user_id, $target_id);
```

The `sendDelayedNotification` function has `sleep(30)` in it to delay its execution. The function then checks if the condition still exists that warrants a notification.

**The issue** is that even though this function fires after the `echo` statement, it delays the response and the request times out. Is there a way to code this so that the response isn't delayed?

Comment: PHP in it's nature is synchronous. What you need is not. Look in to async PHP liblaries like http://reactphp.org/. Use more than one script with queuing system between. Queue would be able to hold for 30 sec before things get executed (Zend queue, zeomq, rabbitmq, gearman)

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment is flushing the output buffer between the response and delayed notification. But that wouldn't be complete because the request would still be active and pending, even though some output has been received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the job in the same script.  The response for your php script won't send until the entire script has finished running.

You will need to have a different script to send notifications.  Have your response set a database record or create a file or something with the time of the initial request.  The notification script would scan the location and send the notifications as appropriate.  Your cancel endpoint would delete/modify the record so that the notification script won't execute.

Comment: How would the different script be executed?

Comment: @inorganik Either daemon that runs in parallel or bad option is to execute shell from php and detach it `exec('php 2nd_script.php  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`

Answer (score 1):

PHP in it's nature is synchronous.

There are few options:

### Easy and bad:

**1st_script.php**

```
<?php 
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => 1,
            'updateUser' => $updateUser['ok'],
            'updateTarget' => $updateTarget['ok'],
            'updateActivity' => $updateActivity['ok']
        )
    );

    exec('php 2nd_script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

**2st_script.php**

```
<?php 
    sleep(30);
    doStuff();
```

### Way better

Run second php script as daemon and use something like http://supervisord.org/ to make sure it does not die.

**1st_script.php**

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => 1,
            'updateUser' => $updateUser['ok'],
            'updateTarget' => $updateTarget['ok'],
            'updateActivity' => $updateActivity['ok']
        )
    );

    submitJobToQueue(data);
```

**2nd_script.php** - script that supervisord runs.

```
<?php

    while(true) {
        $job = getJobOlderThan30Sec();
        executeJobQueue($job);
    }
```

**OR 2nd_script.php** - script that crontab.

```
<?php

    $job = getJobOlderThan30Sec();
    executeJobQueue($job);
```

I've worked with ZendQueue, Gearman and RabbitMQ on large scale projects.
Liked Rabbit most. Gearman had some scalability issues. ZendQueue or any other DB based queue would be easiest but it is pull not push system like others.

### Look in to async libs

like http://reactphp.org

Comment: thanks for your answer. Aside from "easy and bad", just seems a lot simpler to me to set up a cron job instead of research/implement an entire php framework.